# When two <div> tags are side by side, then the content of the left <div> gets shifted as I insert content the right <div>. But I dont want this

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle link for my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Krisalay/zvxxeagh/

MY HTML CODE IS:

```
<div class="MainPanel-sidebarPanelANDContentPanel-Container">
  <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer">
    <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel">
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:orange;">MESSAGE 1</div>
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:lightcoral;">MESSAGE 2</div>
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:orange;">MESSAGE 3</div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel" ng-controller="ProfileController">
    <div class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel">
      <label class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText">ITEM 1</label>
      <label class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText">ITEM 2</label>
      <label class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText">ITEM 3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

THE CSS CODE IS:

```
.MainPanel-sidebarPanelANDContentPanel-Container {
  position: relative;
}

.MainPanel-changableContainer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 23.7%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 76.3%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
}

.MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}

.MainPanel-SidebarPanel {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

I want to **PREVENT** the **Items** in the container **in sidebar** to **automatically shifts** down **as** the **new messages** will **enter** the **chat panel**

[The design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLWww.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes on your style that fixed the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/3s2uv1zc/1/

First in this class .MainPanel-changableContainer I removed the margin-left and make it floated right not left
Then I removed the padding from this class .MainPanel-SidebarPanel and it width now is 23.7%

Your new style should be like this :

```
.MainPanel-sidebarPanelANDContentPanel-Container {
  position: relative;
}

.MainPanel-changableContainer {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 76.3%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
}

.MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}

.MainPanel-SidebarPanel {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 23.7%;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: @Ahmed Salama  and Krisalay : have one small question for you guys ... !!  Dont you think the div which appears first should load first ?? But in your case it is reverse the div with class "MainPanel-changableContainer" is loading first and then div with class "MainPanel-SidebarPanel" is loading. Please inspect it using developer toolbar and see.

Comment: OK, the demo was updated and you can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/3s2uv1zc/2/  , I just add float:left to .MainPanel-SidebarPanel And now it is loading first

Answer (score 0):

That happen because you put the first element in the DOM tree to float left with a `margin-left`.

You can put a `float: right` instead and a `float: left` to the next element to avoid this behavior.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvxxeagh/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this:

```
.MainPanel-changableContainer {
  position: relative;
  float: right; //change
  display: block;
  margin-left: 23.7%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%; //change
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes as follows:

first add this :

```
<div class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel" ng-controller="ProfileController">
    <div class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel">
      <label class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText">ITEM 1</label>
      <label class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText">ITEM 2</label>
      <label class="MainPanel-SidebarPanel-ItemsPanel-ItemText">ITEM 3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and then

```
<div class="MainPanel-changableContainer">
    <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel">
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:orange;">MESSAGE 1</div>
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:lightcoral;">MESSAGE 2</div>
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:orange;">MESSAGE 3</div>
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:orange;">MESSAGE 3</div>
      <div class="MainPanel-changableContainer-chatPanel-MessagePanel" style="background-color:orange;">MESSAGE 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS changes :

```
.MainPanel-changableContainer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  //margin-left: 23.7%;
  //background-color: red;
  width: 73.3%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
}

.MainPanel-SidebarPanel {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 14px;
  float:left;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/zvxxeagh/6/)

let me know if this is what you are looking for...